# How to install boto3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boto3, ubuntu-18.04

How do you install boto3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

I tried this:

```
# pip install boto3

Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python-pip

# apt install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
#
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Partial answer found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/672808/sudo-apt-get-install-python-pip-is-failing

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

*Do not* run `pip install --upgrade pip`, otherwise the following steps are also needed:

from https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240

```
vi /usr/bin/pip3
```

change the broken `from pip import main` import to

```
from pip._internal import main
```

and then finally

```
pip3 install boto3
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex!  Your post help me a lot. By the way, it was not necessary the step of change the /usr/bin/pip3 file.

Answer (score 3):

it's quite simple, just install it from the terminal

```
    apt install python-boto3
```

Comment: Hmm, I got this message "E: Unable to locate package phython-boto3"

Comment: @Bryan_C  this should be `sudo apt-get install python3-boto3` (assuming using Python 3). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76737188/1448678

Answer (score 1):

The log you posted informs you that the commands `pip` and `python-pip` are not already installed. So, if you still use python 2 (do not recommend),  you can install `pip` or `python-pip`

```
sudo apt-get install pip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and then install boto3: `sudo pip install boto3`.

Otherwise, if you already use Python 3, you can just install `pip3` or `python3-pip`

```
sudo apt-get install pip3
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and then install boto3: `sudo pip3 install boto3`

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR**

If trying to install using `apt-get`, try:

`sudo apt-get install python3-boto3`

(obviously for Python 3.x only)

**In general, to use apt to search for and review packages:**

Find packages with `boto3` in name using:

`apt-cache search boto3`

Review any results you're interested in (e.g. `python3-boto3`) with:

`apt-cache show python3-boto3`